# Hypernym for "conjunction" and "disjunction"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, hypernyms, logic

Is there a hypernym for *conjunction* and *disjunction*, in their logical senses? Just using "junction" doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Are you talking about a computer term, or a linguistic term?  If you mean linguistic, then *conjunction* itself suffices. For example, English coördinating conjunctions include *and, but, or, not, yet* — and you will note that *nor* and *or* are disjunctive not conjunctive.

Comment: They are both _logical operators_. But they aren't the only ones.

Comment: "*Connective*" is a term that seems to have served as a hypernym for conjunction, disjunction, negation and conditional (logic).

Comment: (I'm assuming disjunction means `OR` instead of `XOR`). Conjunction, disjunction (of either type), and material implication are dyadic functors, but negation is monadic, and an operator to boot. What distinguishes `AND` and `OR` is that they commute: A and B is equivalent to B and A, and ditto for A or B. Material implication is not commutative. Also, `AND` and `OR` are the functors defined by DeMorgan's Laws, so I could call them the _commutative DeMorgan functors_ if I needed a name; but that's 9 syllables and "and and or" is only three, so I'm not sure I ever would.

Comment: For more details, see the [Logic Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Comment: But @JohnLawler, DeMorgan's Laws can be and often are stated in terms of nand and nor instead of and and or, and nand and nor are also commutative dyadic functors.  One might say complete commutative DeMorgan functors for nand and nor and incomplete commutative DeMorgan functors for and and or.

Comment: Certainly. But the universe of functors is normally chosen minimally and there's rarely a logical reason for NAND or NOR (nor for XOR, for that matter), though there certainly can be a semiconductional reason to prefer that usage. It's like most symmetric differences in math -- you can use a closed set topology or an open set topology, and it's the same topology either way.

Comment: @Xophmeister It seems that you're right and people don't just say "junction", but what a pity!  It seems so clean to say that disjunction and conjunction are both junction.  If I had reason, I think I might use the term unapologetically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably **logical connective**, also called **logical operator**. *Disjunction* and *conjunction* are examples of *binary logical operators*.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective):

> In logic, a logical connective (also called a logical operator) is a symbol or word used to connect two or more sentences (of either a formal or a natural language) in a grammatically valid way, such that the sense of the compound sentence produced depends only on the original sentences.

---

P.S. Conventionally and etymologically, the correct term is **hyperonym**, not <s>hypernym</s>, since the Greek word for "name" is *onoma/onuma*, beginning with an *o*; hence *syn-onym* and *an-onym-ous*, not <s>synnym</s> and <s>anymous</s>.

Comment: Thanks: In which case, it looks like there's no single word that further refines "connectives" to just `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: @Xophmeister: Not to my knowledge...but then you can just say "conjunctions and disjunctions"!

Comment: Etymologically, _hyperonym_ makes more sense from a Greek point of view (though arguably not from an English one); but conventionally, the term is _hypernym_. In all my years studying and working as a linguist, I've never seen anyone actually use _hyperonym_ in the wild. Unlike _synonym_ and _anonymous_, of course, _hypernym_ was coined less than 50 years ago _in English_, so it really only has to adhere to English rules of derivation… and I think most English speakers would consider the suffix to be _-nym_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I believe you and I understand your point. But the conventions I am talking about are not those current among linguists, but among those users of the word who concern themselves with style, in English or otherwise. (Frankly, I don't think anyone else cares at all as long as it's intelligible.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more general term rather than just being restricted to Mathematical Logic, the terms to use are
`Joint`, `Joint-relation` or `Joint-relationship`.

Remember *Relational Databases* (RDBMS)? The term need not pertain to RDBMS, but Relational model syntax exhibits a viable relationship with modern business and legal language usage.

The following are verbs to attain `relationships` or anti-`relationships`:

- conjunct:
  a simultaneous or peer relationship
- adjunct:
  subordinate or auxiliary relationship
- injunct:
  anti-relationship, to prevent a relationship
- disjunct:
  anti-relationship, to disconnect from a relationship

Consider the following extended definition of relationships:

> Inner conjunction, outer conjunction, left-outer conjunction.

To be more specific, the above are for joint-relationships, either to attain a joint or a disjoint.